# Finding an area of the portion of a plane?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help with a problem I got in class today any help would be appreciated!

Find the area of the portion of the portion of the plane $6x+4y+3z=12$ that passes through the first octant where $x, y$, and $z$ are all positive..

I graphed this plane and got all the vertices but I am not sure how my teacher wants us to approach this problem..

Do I calculate the line integral of each side of the triangle separately and add them together? because we are on the section of line integrals, flux, Green's theorem, etc..

Comment: thanks, yea that was what a tutor suggested i use too because we were both stumped!

Answer (score 2):

The $x$, $y$ and $z$ intercepts are $(2,0,0)$, $(0,3,0)$ and $(0,0,4)$ respectively. Fix one of the points, say $(2,0,0)$, and create a vector $\vec u$ from $(2,0,0)$ to $(0,3,0)$ and $\vec v$ from $(2,0,0)$ to $(0,0,4)$. Then one half of the magnitude of the cross product will give us the area.

$\vec u=(0,3,0)-(2,0,0)=(-2,3,0)=-2\hat i+3\hat j$ and $\vec v=(0,0,4)-(2,0,0)=(-2,0,4)=-2\hat i+4\hat k$.

The area = $\frac{1}{2}|\vec u\times \vec v|$ = $\frac{1}{2}|12\hat i+8\hat j+6\hat k|=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{12^2+8^2+6^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{244}= \sqrt{61}$.

Comment: ^^^^YEAP i just figured that out right now too! i bet that is what my teacher was looking for @user69810

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident this isn't what your teacher has in mind, but once you have the three vertices, you can find the three distances between them, and use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the three vertices, you can calculate the length of the three sides and use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)